# Timer ticking only when a button is clicked and passes if statement

Tags: c#

I am new to coding, and I am making a simple clicker game, and have set the timer to tick every second, and start once the program is started. However, nothing is happening, and it only ticks when a button is clicked and the if statements are passed. Any help on how to fix this? I only included one button, but the rest function similarly.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clicks = clicks + (clicker1clicks * clicker1count) + (clicker2clicks * clicker2count) + (clicker3clicks * clicker3count) + (clicker4clicks * clicker4count) + (clicker5clicks * clicker5count);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clicks = clicks + (1 * clickMultiplier);
    string clicksString = clicks.ToString() + clicksText;
    textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
    textBox1.Text = clicksString;
```

Comment: The timer works as expected however since you are just calculating a property/variable it does not refresh in the UI automatically unless you somehow setup notification using INotifyPropertyChanged and some kind of data binding.

In the simplest scenario just include the lines :
    textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
    textBox1.Text = clicksString;

into your timer1_tick event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would like to see the calculated value when the timer ticks updated in the UI.

The following fragment should do it.

```cs
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  clicks = clicks + (clicker1clicks * clicker1count) + (clicker2clicks * clicker2count) + (clicker3clicks * clicker3count) + (clicker4clicks * clicker4count) + (clicker5clicks * clicker5count);
  textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
  textBox1.Text = clicksString;
}
```